# NoClassDefFoundError in Osgi w/ Felix, ant

Tags: java, ant, applet, osgi, noclassdeffounderror

After a lot of work migrating our code to another & fixing all the manifests and the bundles,
when I try to run the applet on the server I get many errors like this one:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jitsi/service/configuration/ConfigurationService
    at net.java.sip.communicator.service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.<init>(AbstractResourcesService.java:127)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.resources.ResourceManagementServiceImpl.<init>(ResourceManagementServiceImpl.java:48)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.resources.ResourceManagementActivator.start(ResourceManagementActivator.java:36)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction$Actions.run(SecureAction.java:1243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:620)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1904)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1822)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jitsi.service.configuration.ConfigurationService not found by [12515]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1426)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:747)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

All the bundles are getting resolved properly, and even when I tried to get some code out of the external jar into our code, it still threw me that error, I know that's a problem in Felix that I need to fix, but I don't know where can I start, all the bundles starting in their proper time...

I'm building the app with ant/Felix.

Maybe it's a problem with the activator? 
Thanks for all the help, love to hear some opinions...

Comment: When you open your applet on the website, do you include all the dependency libraries?

Comment: yes, all of them are included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bundle is using the class `org.jitsi.service.configuration.ConfigurationService` but it doesn't import the package. Make sure that `org.jitsi.service.configuration` is listed in the Import-Package header in your bundle's manifest.

Comment: No. it's not the case all the import are set properly, I think in this case he would throw bundle unresolved error

Comment: it even signs the classes properly, but won't see them in runtime

Comment: can it be the case that my manifest includes import that aren't used by the package? if there's no ambiguity in the manifest, where could it go wrong? I'm pretty new to OSGi...

Comment: No the Import-Package is NOT set correctly, that is exactly why you get this error. I have been using OSGi for ten years, I'm not just guessing.

Comment: You were right, I had an export of this package not in the right place, thanks!